# Regridding latitude and longitude coordinates in a NetCDF file python

Tags: python, coordinates, netcdf, python-xarray, netcdf4

I am working with GOLD Satellite Data. I am trying to regrid the latitude and longitude variables to 1-D.

Right now the lats and lons are given like this, with nlats as the latitude grid dimension, and nlons as the longitude grid dimension.
I want to regrid these into 1-D, in order to select a rectangular area of lats and lons to study.

```
lats   = file.variables['latitude'][:,:]              # Latitude(nlons,nlats)
lons   = file.variables['longitude'][:,:]             # Longitude(nlons,nlats)
```

I tried to select my area using:

```
#defining the latitude values covered 
reallat = lats
reallat[reallat < 24] = np.nan
reallat[reallat > 31] = np.nan

#defining the longitude values covered 
reallon = lons
reallon[reallon < -92] = np.nan
reallon[reallon > -84] = np.nan

#making a list of the coordinates that select good values
loncoord = np.where(~np.isnan(reallon))
latcoord = np.where(~np.isnan(reallat))

#printing means and st devs of disk temperautres corresponding to the right coordinates

print("Average Temps of Longtidue Values")
alon= np.nanmean(tdisk[:,loncoord[0],loncoord[1]])
print(alon)
```

I'm new to python and NetCDF, so I was wondering if it was possible to convert these 2D coordinates into nominal 1D lat/lon dimensions.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I’m not sure I follow the question. What do you mean by nominal 1D coordinates? I don’t see how you can regrid 2d to 1d

Comment: I think it depends whether your grid is regular or not (regular meaning dx and dy are some constants). If yes, then you just take `loncoord =np.unique(reallon)` (without NaNs of course). If it's not regular, meaning you need 2D coordinates, you re-grid (e.g. interpolate) to regular grid.

Comment: @RobertWilson I have a dataset with irregular spaced latitude and longitudes coordinates. My goal is to find the temperature value over a certain rectangle of lat/lon. 2D Longitude and Latitude coordinates occur when the grid lines do not follow lines of constant latitude and longitude. So any projected grid, rotated grid, or curvilinear grid, even if in geographic coordinates, will have 2D longitude and latitude coordinate variables. I'd like to transform the lat and lon arrays to a singular array that I can access with (lat,lon) instead of Latitude(nlons,nlats), Longitude (nlons,nlats)

Comment: Ok. That’s clearer. This is still 2d to 2d. Can you please rewrite the question and either provide the data or specify the grid type? In the meantime you could look up xesmf or mg package nctoolkit which can likely handle the regridding

Comment: @RobertWilson Thanks for the help. I am very new to this type of work. I tried reformatting the question better here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75278947/re-gridding-auxiliary-longitude-and-latitude-coordinates-to-1d-in-order-to-make