# Re-gridding auxiliary longitude and latitude coordinates to 1D in order to make a contour plot of temperature

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, netcdf, python-xarray

I'm working with netcdf4 files and looking to regrid my longitude and latitude coordinates.
The variable descriptions are:

```
float32 latitude(nlats, nlons)
    FORMAT: F7.2
    FIELDNAM: Latitude
    DEPEND_0: nscans
    VALIDMIN: -90.0
    VAR_TYPE: support_data
    LABLAXIS: Latitude
    UNITS: deg
    FILLVAL: nan
    DISPLAY_TYPE: image
    CATDESC: Latitude
    VALIDMAX: 90.0
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (52, 46)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 longitude(nlats, nlons)
    FORMAT: F7.2
    FIELDNAM: Longitude
    DEPEND_0: nscans
    VALIDMIN: -180.0
    VAR_TYPE: data
    LABLAXIS: Longitude
    UNITS: deg
    FILLVAL: nan
    DISPLAY_TYPE: image
    CATDESC: Longitude
    VALIDMAX: 180.0
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (52, 46)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used

    FORMAT:        F10.3
    DEPEND_1:      nlats
    FIELDNAM:      TDISK
    DEPEND_0:      nscans
    VALIDMIN:      0.0
    LABLAXIS:      Retrieved Temperature
           ...
    UNITS:         K
    VAR_TYPE:      data
    FILLVAL:       nan
    DISPLAY_TYPE:  image
    CATDESC:       Disk neutral temperature
    VALIDMAX:      10000.0, 'time_utc': <xarray.Variable (nscans: 68, nlats: 52, nlons: 46)>
```

The problem is there is two dimensional latitude and longitude coordinate variables and there's not a direct way to find array indices from latitude and longitude coordinates.

[image: Here's the input grid points, which lie on a curvilinear grid. The next figure is what I would like to do a contour of.]
I am trying to find a way to make the figure with y=latitude and x=longitude, instead of the indexes (nlats, nlons)

My longitude and latitude are 2D netCDF variables of shape (52, 46) indexed by nlats and nlons dimensions, 2392 values for each which include many nan values.

The temperature variable that I want to plot has auxillary longitude and lattitude coordinates, I want to access data corresponding to their values, rather than nlons and nlats array indicies.
I was able to determine values of netCDF variables such as temperature at, for example, the grid point closest to 62 degrees north latitude and 12 degrees east longitude

```
def tunnel_fast(latvar,lonvar,lat0,lon0):
    '''
    Find closest point in a set of (lat,lon) points to specified point
    latvar - 2D latitude variable from an open netCDF dataset
    lonvar - 2D longitude variable from an open netCDF dataset
    lat0,lon0 - query point
    Returns iy,ix such that the square of the tunnel distance
    between (latval[it,ix],lonval[iy,ix]) and (lat0,lon0)
    is minimum.
    '''
    rad_factor = pi/180.0 # for trignometry, need angles in radians
    # Read latitude and longitude from file into numpy arrays
    latvals = latvar[:] * rad_factor
    lonvals = lonvar[:] * rad_factor
    ny,nx = latvals.shape
    lat0_rad = lat0 * rad_factor
    lon0_rad = lon0 * rad_factor
    # Compute numpy arrays for all values, no loops
    clat,clon = cos(latvals),cos(lonvals)
    slat,slon = sin(latvals),sin(lonvals)
    delX = cos(lat0_rad)*cos(lon0_rad) - clat*clon
    delY = cos(lat0_rad)*sin(lon0_rad) - clat*slon
    delZ = sin(lat0_rad) - slat;
    dist_sq = delX**2 + delY**2 + delZ**2
    minindex_1d = dist_sq.argmin()  # 1D index of minimum element
    iy_min,ix_min = np.unravel_index(minindex_1d, latvals.shape)
    return iy_min,ix_min


iy,ix = tunnel_fast(latvar, lonvar, 62.0, 12.0)
print('Closest lat lon:', latvar[iy,ix], lonvar[iy,ix])
tempvar = ncfile.variables['tdisk']
print('temperature:', tempvar[:,iy, ix])
```

This retrieves the closes lat and lon, in this case: 57.364464 1.5607127, and the temperature at that point.

I would like to access all the data on a subgrid defined within a specified space coordinate bounding box, and make a contour plot of temperature on this subgrid.

Comment: Its not 100% clear what you are after. It looks like tricontour and tripcolor should work with your data.  https://matplotlib.org/stable/plot_types/index.html#unstructured-coordinates

Comment: @JodyKlymak thanks! I wasn't aware of these functions I should be able to work something out with this